# Can I make this assumption about this limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given $ a,x \in \mathbb{R}^N $

And

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac {f(x,a)}{\|x - a\|} = 0$

As

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \|x - a\| = 0 $

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac {f(x,a)}{\|x - a\|}$  should be $ \pm \infty$ if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x,a) \in R \backslash \{0\} $ and at least non zero if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x,a) = \pm\infty$

So I should be able to make the assumption

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x,a)$ = 0

It seems to me that this logically must be true, but I am missing something. This limit does have to exist does in not?

Comment: The epsilon-delta characterization of limits shows that indeed $\lim f(x,a)=0$.